# Adding a once off triggering of a systemd timer

Tags: systemd, systemd-timers

I have a systemd timer which runs at 23:00 on Fridays in order to do some batch data processing once a week during low demand times. It is Tuesday, and I would like to test a change I have made, I would like it to start at 23:00 today, so that I can check it tomorrow, rather than having to wait until next Monday.

Is there an easy & build in way to schedule a once-off triggering of a systemd timer? e.g. `systemd trigger-timer --timer whatever.timer --at 2021-06-22T23:00` or something? I want it only to start at this time, I don't want to add a new recurring rule. I want it to run as regular every Friday at 23:00 and today at 23:00.

I'm sure I could hack something together with `sleep 10hr ; systemctl start whatever.service` or maybe manually edit the `/etc/systemd/system/whatever.timer` file, but if there's is a proper way to do "once off" triggerings of a timer, I would prefer to use that.

This is on Ubuntu Linux 20.04 & 18.04, whatever version of systemd that is (245?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a

```
OnCalendar=2021-06-22T23:00
```

to your timer unit file. Then remove it after you are done. Or if you just want to trigger the service, you could do:

```
systemd-run --on-calendar=2021-06-22T23:00 systemctl start example.service
```

Answer (score 3):

A one-off triggering of a timer is not a timer, and a one-off firing of the service can be achieved with `at` or using a cron.

`at 23:00 <<<"systemctl start example.service"` would be fairly equivalent to what you're looking for.

Comment: I understand the need for testing in as similar a way as the real timer. This is the best I can come up with but I'm curious if anyone knows of a better way.

Comment: `at` is the way.